# Set scroll position in Firefox instantly?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have a looping scroll box that puts you back at the beginning when you scroll past a certain point.

In Chrome/Edge it happens instantly making it seamless, but in Firefox it does some kind of smooth scroll to the position which looks really bad in this setup. (It seems to depend on the speed you are scrolling to see the glitch)

I have also tried `scrollTo` with behavior set to 'instant', and setting css `scroll-behavior`, but the problem is the same.

Is there any way to fix this?

```js
var list = document.querySelector('ul');

list.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if (list.scrollTop > 300) {
        list.scrollTop = 0;
    };
});
```

```css
ul {height:200px; overflow-y:scroll;}
li {background:lightgrey; line-height:90px; margin-bottom:10px;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you set [scoll-behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior) in CSS?

Comment: @Reyno Yes, I tried that too, but it didn't seem to make any difference.